# How to obtain number of entries in ELF's symbol table?

Tags: elf

Consider standard hello world program in C compiled using GCC without any switches. As `readelf -s` says, it contains 64 symbols. It says also that `.symtab` section is 1024 bytes long. However each symbol table entry has 18 bytes, so how it is possible it contains 64 entries? It should be 56 entries. I'm constructing my own program which reads symbol table and it does not see those "missing" entries as it reads till section end. How readelf knows how long to read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As one can see in [elf.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/elf.h#L201), symbol entry structure looks like that:

```
typedef struct elf32_sym {
  Elf32_Word    st_name;
  Elf32_Addr    st_value;
  Elf32_Word    st_size;
  unsigned char st_info;
  unsigned char st_other;
  Elf32_Half    st_shndx;
} Elf32_Sym;
```

`Elf32_Word` and `Elf32_Addr` are 32 bit values, `Elf32_Half' is 16 bit, chars are 8 bit. That means that size of structure is 16 not 18 bytes. Therefore 1024 bytes long section gives exactly 64 entries.

Answer (score 1):

The entries are aligned to each other and padded with blanks, therefore the size mismatch. Check out [this mailthread](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2006-08/msg00132.html) for a similar discussion.

As for your code, I suggest to check out the [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) for readelf, especially the function `process_symbol_table()` in *binutils/readelf.c*.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but if entries were anyhow padded, would a lesser number of them be contained in 1024 bytes? I do not see any padding, because by reading entries one directly after another I get exactly the same results as 56 first entries reported by readelf. And if I read some more I will also have good results. The problem is: how would I know where to end? Size reported in `.symtab` section header is 1024 bytes and standard says about this value "This member gives the section’s size in bytes."

Answer (score 0):

The file size of an ELF data type can differ from the size of its in-memory representation.

You can use the [elf32_fsize()](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=elf32_fsize&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and [elf64_fsize()](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=elf32_fsize&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) functions in [libelf](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/wiki/libelf) to retrieve the file size of an ELF data type.